# Main Class com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance not found

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I recently installed GPE for eclipse Luna 4.4. However, I have to use jre 1.6 instead of jre 1.7. After modifying the Build Path and changing the JRE 1.7 to JRE 1.6. I am getting an JVM error "Main Class com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance not found". Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Plugin for Eclipse is compiled for Java 1.7. The byte code will not run in a Java 1.6 VM. If you really have to use Java 1.6, you cannot use the GPE.

As of [two years ago](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java6), App Engine removed Java 6 support. It now only supports Java 7 (and Java 8 if it's set to compile for Java 7). So with or without the plugin, you need to upgrade to Java 7 if you're going to deploy and run your app on App Engine.